# How to save the name of the file if it is being treated in the script

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I have 88 folders, each of which contains the file "pair.'numbers'." (pair.3472, pair.7829 and so on). I need to treat the files with awk to extract the second column, but I need to save the numbers. If I try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..88}; do 
    awk '{print $2}' ~/Documents/attempt.$i/pair* > ~/Results/pred.pair*
done
```

It doesn't save the numbers, but gives only one file: `pred.pair*`

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop (and see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for why that's a Good Thing):

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out=FILENAME; sub(/\/Documents.*\//,"/Results/pred.",out) }
    { print $2 > out }
' ~/Documents/attempt.{1..88}/pair*
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it: `awk` has a `FILENAME` variable and you can redirect the output from within your `awk` script to a manipulated string which is based on `FILENAME`.

Or you can do it with `bash`

```
for i in {1..88}; do
  to_be_processed_fname=$(ls ~/Documents/attempt.$i/pair*)
  extension="${to_be_processed_fname/*./}"   
  awk '{print $2}' "${to_be_processed_fname}" > "$HOME/Results/pred.${extension}"
done
```

Now the above of course fails if you have more than one `pair*` files within the same directory. But I'm leaving that to you.

Comment: Always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not quoting them and fully understand all of the implications (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/133219). Use `$(...)` instead of deprecated backticks (http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/133219). Avoid writing loops in shell (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..88}; do 
    awk '{fname=FILENAME;sub(".*/", "", fname);print $2 > ("~/Results/pred."fname)}' ~/Documents/attempt.$i/pair*
done
```

Use AWK build in variable `FILENAME`. We need to get the basename `fname` from `FILENAME`. Then redirect `$2` value to `"~/Results/pred."fname`